# Warning and Fatal error calling require_once()

Tags: php, include, require-once

I want to fetch div element from other website .

on which iam having my profile, i have tried using this code.

```
require_once('../simple_html_dom.php');

$html=file_get_html('http://www.example.com');
$ret=$html->find("div[id=frame-gallery]");
$ret=array_shift($ret);
echo($ret);
```

but this code is giving errors

> Warning:
>   require_once(../simple_html_dom.php)
>   [function.require-once]: failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory
>   in
>   E:\wamp\www\in.com\components\com_content\view.php
>   on line 22
>
> Fatal error: require_once()
>   [function.require]: Failed opening
>   required '../simple_html_dom.php'
>   (include_path='.;./includes;./pear')
>   in
>   E:\wamp\www\in.com\components\com_content\view.php
>   on line 22

iam stuck with this plz help me with the code snippets for fetching the specific div element from a website

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file `simple_html_dom.php` is not where you're telling PHP to look for it.

```
require_once('../simple_html_dom.php');
```

To be safe, try using the full path instead of a relative path.

```
require_once('E:\wamp\www\in.com\components\simple_html_dom.php');
```

BTW, if the full path above is incorrect, then that is your problem. This is the path that PHP is trying.

**To clarify**: I'm only suggesting the OP switch to absolute paths to identify and confirm the source of the issue. Going to production with absolute paths is rarely a good idea.

Comment: @Maerlyn: To still ensure portability you may defined a constant in the index.php file, e.g. `const ROOT = __DIR__;`. But imho relative paths are absolutely okay, at least I never had problems with them ;)

Comment: I agree, relative paths are ok :)

Comment: @Maerlyn: I didn't mean to suggest the OP switch to absolute paths. See the clarification at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot... that solved my problems, but one more thing the div iam fetching is all images & logos and it is displaying in one row........ and i want to format it in a 3/3 grid.....how to go about that.

Comment: You need to open a new question :)

Answer (score 1):

require and include paths can be tricky in PHP. Try to use full paths when you can. You'll find $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] usefull for that.

Answer (score 0):

Your inlude_path should contain ".", which means current directory.

But if you having troubles with including file by relative name, then just try to use absolute names, like require_once('E:\wamp\www\in.com\components\simple_html_dom.php');

But better it should be:

`require_once 'E:/wamp/www/in.com/components/simple_html_dom.php';`

Comment: No, you don't need to have `.` in the `include_path`. PHP takes `include_path` only into account if the path is neither a stream wrapper, nor absolute, nor relative (and it is relative in this case.)